# How do I accept mouse inputs in Java?

Tags: java, input

I am very new to Java, and I wanted to try to make a thing in BlueJ that requires BlueJ to know when the mouse is clicked, and to be able to determine the mouse's coordinates on the x,y plane.

In my class where I code, I have seen some imported class and things like Scanner and Graphics, so it might be something along those lines, but I am not sure.

I just mainly need

- The thing to import (if it is a thing that needs to be imported)
- How to make it tell if the mouse is clicked
- How to make it be able to tell me the x, y position of the mouse when asked (like, what class method would I have to refer to to find this)

After I have that, I will work with that to try to make my program. Thank you!

EDIT: Upon request, here is my attempt

```
java.awt.event.MouseAdapter

public class main
{
 MouseAdapter test = new MouseAdapter();

}

public void mouseMoved(test e)
{
    System.out.println("hey your mouse moved");
}
```

I am clearly doing something horribly wrong

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: I have no clue. I am using BlueJ that lets me compile code in Java. I think its JDK?

Comment: Include your code so far it will help a lot

Comment: Okay, I did. I am sorry I am new to this site and coding and I am probably breaking every rule of ettiquete here (source: my post's score is at -3)

Comment: The very first search result on google can answer this.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html , because this isnt very helpful considering my lack of knowledge

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html would be better here's an example of listening to a mouse

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your goal would be to use java swing. The following code will print out a statement if the mouse is moved inside the created window:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
            jFrame.setSize(720,480);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrame.getContentPane().addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    System.out.println("STUFF");
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    System.out.println("STUFF");

                }
            });

        });
    }
```

This is not an ideal solution but I hope it helps you to look in the right direciton.